# Laravel 5 Global Mutator to escape all html chars?

Tags: laravel, xss, sanitization, htmlspecialchars

Building an API but because I am dynamically creating tables etc in Vue.js from the API response I can't make use of blades html escaping.

I know in my model I can use a mutator:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
    return strtolower($value); // example
}
```

But we have a lot fields that can be edited across many models. Is there a way I can automatically return all values with htmlspecialchars()?

Or is the only option to change the API responses to run htmlspecialchars() on every field?

Thanks.

EDIT: Using Laravel Spark. Suggested answer was to create a new model and extend that on our models but the Spark models already have a long list of extended classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class which extends `Model` class and make all you models extend this class instead of `Model`. In the class override [`getAttributeValue`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Eloquent/Model.php#L2632) method:

```
protected function getAttributeValue($key)
{
    $value = $this->getAttributeFromArray($key);

    if ($this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
        return $this->mutateAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    if ($this->hasCast($key)) {
        return $this->castAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    if (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) && ! is_null($value)) {
        return $this->asDateTime($value);
    }

    return is_string($value) ? htmlspecialchars($value) : $value;
}
```

Comment: That was my initial thinking. I'll go back and edit the question but I am actually using Laravel Spark. Our custom models are okay to do this, but the Spark User model for example extends SparkUser, which then extends Authenticatable and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from extending classes. Alternate solution is to use traits.

Create a new trait

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait ExtendedModel {

    public function getNameAttribute($value) 
    {
        return strtolower($value); // example
    }
}
```

Use traits in required models:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\ExtendedModel;

class MyTable extends Model
{
    use ExtendedModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this.

I would make a trait and then attach this trait to all models where you want it.

The trait would overrider `getAttributeValue($key)` method with your own logic. Like this:

```
trait CastAttributes {

    public function getAttributeValue($value) 
    {
        $value = $this->getAttributeValue($value);
        return is_string($value) ? strtolower($this->getAttributeValue($value)) : $val;
    }
}
```

That beign said, you will most likely not want to cast absolutely everything. In that case I would do this:

```
trait CastAttributes {

    protected $toLower = [];

    public function getAttributeValue($key) 
    {
        $value = $this->getAttributeValue($key);
        return in_array($key, $this->toLower) ? strtolower($value) : $value;
    }
}
```

And then override the `$toLower` array with all the attributes that you actually want cast to lower case.